# ng-repeat not working , when used in <li> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

`span` is not displayed but the button in the `li` tag is being displayed if `ng-repeat` is not used , but once i use `ng-repeat` , neither the `span` nor the button is being displayed.
I have used `ng-repeat` numerous times but never faced such a situation, both `span` and button elements are not displayed if I use `ng-repeat` in the `li` tag.

This is the **index.html** file:

```
<ul id="contactdelete">
    <li ng-repeat="contact in $ctrl.contacts">
        <span>{{contact.name}}</span>
        <button ng-click="$ctrl.deletecontact()">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the **controller.js** file

```
(function() {

    class ContactsComponent {
        constructor($http) {

            var result;

            $http.get("/api/contacts/").success(function(response) {

                result = response;

            });

            this.contacts = result;
        }
    }

    angular.module('myApp')
        .component('contacts', {
            templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contacts.html',
            controller: ContactsComponent
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.contacts` is empty as the `success` callback is async and its context is different from the constructor, which is why you can't use `this` directly.

Also, you should use the [`then`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) function which takes 2 functions as arguments, one for success, the other as an error callback.

One way to work around this is making `this` a local variable, then using it inside the callback.

```
var self = this;
$http.get("/api/contacts/").then(function(response){

    self.contacts = response; // or response.data, depending of what you're receiving.

});
```

Or you could use the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
$http.get("/api/contacts/").then(function(response){
    this.contacts = response; 

}.bind(this)); // notice the bind here
```

Angular provides its own [`bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) implementation:

```
$http.get("/api/contacts/").then(angular.bind(this, function(response){

    this.contacts = response;

}));
```

Additional informations on scope and context:

- [Understanding Scope and Context in JavaScript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)
- [`this` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/1218980)

Comment: thanks man !.... but there were many instances where i used 'this' keyword . for example while using ng-model="$ctrl.logo" in the html file , i use this keyword for logo in the js file , but why cant i use the same syntax which i have been using for months , instead why should i create something called self again ?

Comment: the `this` keyword refers to the context of the innermost function. The callbacks have their own context, which is not the context of the controller's constructor. Local variables are accessible from within a callback if defined inline, but the `this` value will change. You can inject the context with which a function is called with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or `apply`. To override the context of a callback and ensure that `this` is what you want, you may use `bind` as my second example.

Comment: can you suggest a source , where i can learn about this in detail !

Comment: I added links to the end of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should move `this.contacts = result;` to inside success function:

```
 $http.get("/api/contacts/").success(function(response){

     result = response;
     this.contacts = result;

  });
```

And i think you have to user `result = response.data` instead of `result = response`

Comment: Did you try `result = response.data`?

Comment: What do you get when u `console.log(response)`?